# Deformation of an image between four points

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, geometry

I have recently been working on my graphic engine, and after creating a texture loader and displayer, I now want to transform this loaded textures by deforming them.

For example, I have a texture defined between this for points a(0,0), b(0, 1), c(1, 0) and d(1, 1). But now I want the point d to be d(1, 2) and still being capable of drawing the texture in.

[image: fig 1 : streching the image]

When I load the image, i get a list of list of points in RGBA (or RBG). To display the texture, I just draw it points by points.

```
def drawTexture(self, x, y, texture):
    for i in range(len(texture.pixels)):
        for j in range(len(texture.pixels[i])):
            if len(texture.pixels[i][j]) == 4:
                texture.pixels[i][j] = (texture.pixels[i][j][0], texture.pixels[i][j][1], texture.pixels[i][j][2], PickTheNearest(0, 1, texture.pixels[i][j][3]))
            self.drawPixel(i+x, j+y, self.HexFromRgb(texture.pixels[i][j]))
```

How can I make it to be streched inside this quad ?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a projective transformation do the job?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote some code based on projective geometry and implemented as a series of linear algebra calculations. Given the unit square in the first quadrant and a (convex) quadrilateral with four vertex points, the code constructs the (unique within the framework of projective geometry) projective transformation that maps the square to the more general quad. It should work for your case too.

The idea is to generate the texture in the square, as you can do already, and then map the texture via the projective map to make it fit in the new quadrilateral.

```py
import numpy as np

def scale(Quad):
    factors = np.linalg.solve(Quad[1:4,:].T, Quad[0,:])
    factors[2] = -factors[2]
    factors = np.concatenate((np.array([1]), factors))   
    return np.diag(factors)

def proj_matrix(Square, Quad):
    Scale = scale(Quad)
    U = (Square.T).dot(Square)
    U = np.linalg.inv(U)
    U = U.dot(Square.T)
    U = U.dot(Scale)
    U = U.dot(Quad)
    return U, np.linalg.inv(Scale)

def proj_map(x, Matrix, Scale):
    y = Scale.dot(x.dot(Matrix))
    return y


'''
Test 1:
'''

P = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [2,1,1],
              [1,3,1],
              [3,2,1]])

E = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [1,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [1,1,1]])

U, D = proj_matrix(E, P)

P_ = proj_map(E, U, D)

print(P_)

'''
Test 2:
'''

P = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [1,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [1,2,1]])

E = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [1,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [1,1,1]])

U, D = proj_matrix(E, P)

P_ = proj_map(E, U, D)

print(P_)
```